# Combine two files chunked in this format XXXXX.csv.gz_1_2.tar & XXXXX.csv.gz_2_2.tar (with python or pyspark)

Tags: python, linux, gzip, tar, apache-zeppelin

I have two files with this format `XXXX.csv.gz_1_2.tar & XXXX.csv.gz_2_2.tar`, my goal is to combine those files to be able to unzip the complete file in order to get the csv file.

Can you help me please ?

I tried to use `tar` or `cat` function from linux cmd with import os like:

```
import os

cat="cat C:/Users/AAAA/XXXX.csv.gz_1_2.tar C:/Users/AAAA/XXXX.csv.gz_2_2.tar > C:/Users/AAAA/XXXX.csv.gz.tar "

os.system(cat)
```

Thank you !

Comment: you would need : 1) untar / uncompress the gz.tar to extract the csv files from both files. (tar/gz are compress & archive format) 2) Concatenate the two csv text files, taking into account if any header row is present (in this case you will obviously need to remove the second file's header row) and then (Optional) 3) tar/compress the result. . In any case, regarding your attempt, you cannot use `cat` to concatenate two binary files (tar.gz files are binary)

Comment: Why the `[linux]` tag and `C:` starting pathnames?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add files from one tar into another tar in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17616340/add-files-from-one-tar-into-another-tar-in-python)

Comment: You can very easily adapt the code in the question and the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17616340/add-files-from-one-tar-into-another-tar-in-python

Comment: "Add files from one tar into another tar in python"  it's really not the same problem but thank you.

Comment: Thank a lot "Pac0", i read a lot of subject about tar.gz but for gz_x_x.tar what is the process please ?

Answer (score 1):

The code below is (almost) completely stolen from [Add files from one tar into another tar in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17616340/add-files-from-one-tar-into-another-tar-in-python), with the obvious adaptation of using two (or any number) of original tar files.

```
import tarfile

old_tars = ("….tar", "….tar.gz", "….tar.xz", …)

with tarfile.open("new.tar", "w") as new_tar:
    for old_tar in (tarfile.open(tar_name, "r") for tar_name in old_tars):
        for member in old_tar.getmembers():
            new_tar.addfile(member, old_tar.extractfile(member.name))
        old_tar.close()
```

(of course in a real world program the names of the tar files wouldn't be not hard-coded into the source).